# How to position an image element in the middle of the viewport?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I was searching for the following solution.
I want to position an image element, like `<img src='placehold.png' alt=''>` in the middle of the middle. So the height is the height of the viewport and the width will automatically set and the middle of the image should be in the middle of the viewport width.

A example what I search for is like the following website; http://bravepeople.co/

Comment: Do you want to position the image element such that it is both horizontally and vertically centered?

Comment: I have got a short tutorial/code snippit for that. http://www.sidneydobber.com/a-way-to-dynamically-center-an-html-element-with-css-and-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution to center vertically and horizontally is using javascript:

```
function centerElement(elem){
    elem.style.position="absolute";
    elem.style.top=(window.innerHeight-image.offsetHeight)/2+"px";
    elem.style.left=(window.innerWidth-image.offsetWidth)/2+"px";
}
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/natchkebiailia/Wys3w/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="placehold.png" alt="" style="margin: 0px auto;">
```

Comment: you should also add `display:block;`

Answer (score 0):

try this to the image container:

```
style {
text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the link, it seems that you want to position the image as a background image? Instead of declaring it within a `<img>` element, use the image URL as a background image of the parent container, and use the following code:

```
div {
    background-image: url(placehold.png);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    /* Or background-size: contain; if you want to keep the full image in view */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/8guRR/

Otherwise, if you want to keep it as a standalone element, you can use the following HTML:

```
<div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/2048x1600" />
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
div img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/wPuNs/